# Copying the contents of a file into another file at a point relative to the end of the file

Tags: shell, awk, sed, posix, sh

New to StackExchange, forgive me for errors.

I have an input file that needs to be copied into another file, before the last character.

inputfile.txt:

```
input {
       "inputstuff"
}
```

filetowriteto.txt:

```
Stuff {
       foo {
            "foostuff"
       }
       bar {
            "barstuff"
       }
}
```

After running the script, the resulting file should now be:

filetowriteto.txt:

```
Stuff {
       foo {
            "foostuff"
       }
       bar {
            "barstuff"
       }
       input {
              "inputstuff"
       }
}
```

Basically the script copies the `input` set of lines and pastes them just before the last right bracket in `filetowriteto.txt`.

The script can't rely on line counts, since `filetowriteto.txt` doesn't have a predicable amount of foo or bar lines, and I don't know how to use sed or awk to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{ if (NR>1) print last; last=$0; next} {print "       " $0} END{print last}' filetowriteto.txt inputfile.txt 
Stuff {
       foo {
            "foostuff"
       }
       bar {
            "barstuff"
       }
       input {
              "inputstuff"
       }
}
```

To change the file in place:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ if (NR>1) print last; last=$0; next} {print "       " $0} END{print last}' filetowriteto.txt inputfile.txt >tmp && mv tmp filetowriteto.txt
```

#### How it works

- `FNR==NR{ if (NR>1) print last; last=$0; next}`

  While reading the first file, (a) if we are not on the first line, print the value of `last`, (b) assign the text of the current line to `last`, and (c) skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.

  This uses a common awk trick.  The condition `FNR==NR` is only true while we are reading the first file.  This is because, in awk, NR is the number of lines that we have read so far while FNR is the number of lines that we have read so far from the current file.  Thus, `FNR==NR` is only true when we are reading from the first file.
- `print "       " $0`

  While reading the second file, print each line with some leading white space.
- `END{print last}`

  After we have finished printing the second file, print the last line of the first file.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
$ cat /tmp/f1.txt
input {
       "inputstuff"
}
$ cat /tmp/f2.txt
Stuff {
       foo {
            "foostuff"
       }
       bar {
            "barstuff"
       }
}
```

You can use [command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) to achieve this:

```
$ ( sed '$d' f2.txt ; cat f1.txt ; tail -n1 f2.txt )
```

or (this version does not create a sub shell)

```
$ { sed '$d' f2.txt ; cat f1.txt ; tail -n1 f2.txt; }
```

How does it work?

1. `sed '$d' f2.txt` prints all but the last line of f2.txt
2. `cat f1.txt` prints f1.txt at that point
3. `tail -n1 f2.txt` print the last line of f2 now

If you want to indent f1.txt, use sed instead of cat. You can also use sed to print the last line:

```
$ { sed '$d' /tmp/f2.txt ; sed 's/^/       /' /tmp/f1.txt ; sed -n '$p' /tmp/f2.txt;  } 
Stuff {
       foo {
            "foostuff"
       }
       bar {
            "barstuff"
       }
       input {
              "inputstuff"
       }
}
```

And then you can redirect the output of the grouping to a file if you wish with a `>` redirect.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    rec = (NR>1 ? rec ORS : "") $0
    next
}
FNR>1 {
    print prev
    if ( sub(/[^[:space:]].*/,"",prev) ) {
        indent = prev
    }
}
{ prev=$0 }
END {
    gsub(ORS,ORS indent,rec)
    print indent rec ORS prev
}

$ awk -f tst.awk inputfile.txt filetowriteto.txt
Stuff {
       foo {
            "foostuff"
       }
       bar {
            "barstuff"
       }
       input {
              "inputstuff"
       }
}
```

The above uses the indentation from the last non-blank line before the last line of the file to be modified to set the indentation for the new file it's inserting.